# c# xml deserialize

Tags: c#, xml, deserialize

Нужно десериализовать `xml` файл с `1c`. Для дальнейшей работы сам файл  менять нету смысла так как он генерируется платформой автоматически.

Сам
**[.xml](https://pastebin.com/2HgrUJEQ)**

код C#

```
ЭДПФР test = null;
        string path = @".\test.XML";
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ЭДПФР));
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                test = (ЭДПФР)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

                MessageBox.Show(test.СЗВТД.Руководитель.ФИО.Фамилия);
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
```

модель данных **[link](https://pastebin.com/PXWTHFC4)**

*Ошибка:*

> System.InvalidOperationException: "В документе XML (2, 2) присутствует ошибка." InvalidOperationException: <ЭДПФР xmlns='http://пф.рф/СЗВ-ТД/2020-09-26'> не ожидался.

[проект на github](https://github.com/tatflot/sbpfr_xml)

Comment: StringReader читает из строки , а не из файла. Почему вы не использовали File.Open или File.OpenRead?

Comment: `StringReader` замените на `StreamReader`

Comment: да, подправил с using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(path)) на using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
ну теперь ругается на атрибуты 
InvalidOperationException: <ЭДПФР xmlns='http://пф.рф/СЗВ-ТД/2020-09-26'> не ожидался.

Comment: Модель данных покажите, давайте без гаданий по звездам. Вопрос можно редактировать. И обновите код.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/PXWTHFC4

Comment: Код надо вставлять прямо в текст вопроса, неизвестно какими лицензионными ограничениями может быть защищен код, расположенный на стороннем ресурсе, а вставленный в вопрос - открыт лицензией Creative Commons. Но если вопрос решен, то это уже не важно.

Answer (score 0):

решил проблему специальной вставкой xml в класс
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]